# change crystal report object text at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I need to change crystal report object text at runtime?

For example :

> original text => true runtime text => accept

I am working with crystal report 13.

My field data type (bit) and connect with (linq to sql) to crystal report

Now change bit field text (true or false) in crystal report to (accept or not accept)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, could you rephrase?

Comment: Are these text objects pre-defined, or they have to be created dynamically?

Comment: working with lnq to sql. pre-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You May use formula instead

create a formula and put some code like following in it :

```
 If myDataSource.myDataField = true Then "accept" Else "reject"
```

You could use this formula like a data source field and put it whereever in your report